# Azure 1GB Shared Account, Disk Out of Space

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created an App and published through Visual Studio. Package size is just 20MB and it does not write/upload anything on the file system but after 2 weeks I can't publish my changes to App and getting error that disk is out of space.

I checked din the quota and it says 1GB has been consumed. I have only 1 app.
Is there any way to explore files and check which file is taking this much space?

Comment: if your app is at `myservice.azurewebsites.net`, then go to `myservice.scm.azurewebsites.net` Then, at the top, there is a "Debug Console" which will let you browse around with a command prompt.

Comment: Thank you. I found there is a log file generated with my code and that is taking lot of space. If I just delete the file through command prompt, do I need to do something else to refresh the space?

Comment: now it is saying, app quota has been reached and app has been stopped. I have stopped logging information in my app website and ready to publish my code. Can I delete all existing files?

Comment: if you are re-publishing, then you should be able to delete the files in the wwwroot directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the quota of your webapp in kudu site.

[image]

And you can use

```
dir /a/s
```

to foreach fils under wwwroot and you can see how much space the files takes up.

[image]